# Downloads & Safari Extension

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I wrote an application that runs in the background and periodically scans my download folder and moves files to different folders based on their type. I want rewrite this application as a safari extensions, but I didn't find a way to intercept downloads. All in all the ExtensionAPI seems to be very limited and seems to focus a lot on little eye-candy apps.

Is it possible to intercept and redirect downloads through the ExentsionAPI?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot access the hard drive through the Extension API.